# Spark SQL how to query subset of struct fields in Array[Struct]?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in Hive, which has a schema:

```
root
 |-- startdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- enddate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- .......: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- otherfields: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to get only _id and name column from items array fields i.e.:

```
|-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

is there a way to do that without additional transformations in Spark itself, so that only actual columns were only retrieved from Hive ?

I'm using Spark 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
data.select("items._id", "items.name")
```

Although it might result in:

```
root
 |-- _id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

In Spark 2.4+ you could try leveraging [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#arrays_zip-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-)

Comment: yes, I have tried it and it results in two separate arrays. Unfortunately as I said I'm on Spark 2.2. Is there any way to do that without additional transformations in Spark itself ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can without using a UDF

Comment: Maybe the real question is: What are trying to achieve with this? And why not just using a UDF? :)

Comment: I try to not load redundant data to save time and memory

Comment: Keep in mind that saving time/memory might depend on whether your underlying storage format supports this kind of partitioning/optimization. I don't know the details of how different serialization formats deal with array and whether it's possible to push this computation all the way down to reduce I/O and network bandwidth. IMO: Once loaded, using "pure Spark functions " over an UDF might only achieve little (and possible unnoticeable) gains